# How to set Popup panel index that will overlay other controls in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem on how to correctly set the Panel.ZIndex of a Popup inside a Grid.  The goal is that when I click the Emergency button, a Popup window will display with an image on it and overlay (cover) the buttons (see screenshot below).

I have set the Grid `Panel.ZIndex="0"`and the Popup to `Panel.ZIndex="1"`  However, the Popup window doesn't overlay the buttons.

This is the XAML implementation.

```
<StackPanel Background="Black">
    <Grid Background="#253341" Panel.ZIndex="0">
        <Popup HorizontalOffset="-5" VerticalOffset="0" IsOpen="False" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Name="EmergencyPopup" Placement="RelativePoint" AllowsTransparency="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=EmergencyButton}"
               Width="1080" Height="1920" Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource EdenParkInfoImg}"/>
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="25"
                           MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown">close X</Label>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Screenshot of the Popup window and buttons (the red box indicates that the image inside the Popup is behind the buttons)
[image]

Have I correctly set the Panel.ZIndex of the Grid and Popup? What is the correct way of doing it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you mark which is the popup in above image?

Comment: @SatyajitMohanty, the Popup dialog is the big image that you see.  Please take a look at this image [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA).  The highlight in green box is the Popup dialog.  And in xaml, the name of the Popup is EmergencyPopup.

Comment: @SatyajitMohanty, do you have an idea how to set the ZIndex of the Popup to be on top of the other controls (i.e. Emergency Information, Feedback, Accessibility buttons)?

Comment: @Juniuz it should work without defining ZIndex, are you sure the isopen set to true while clicking Emergency button?

Comment: @Juniuz Please show complete markup of your `Page/Window`

Comment: If you want more control over Popup placement/coverage [Rachel's blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) might be of interest. Her custom Popup Control can be used to cover (any panel holding) the buttons, as if the Popup was a child to that panel (positioning).

Comment: Popup control's visual tree is completely different and independent from the control on which it is opened. You can see that in snoop. I agree that it should by default have highest Z order. We may need bit more code. Please post the parent control code, the popup code and how popup is opened.

Comment: @WPFUser, yes the IsOpen property is set to true while the Emergency button is clicked.  You can refer the complete code of MainWindow through this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA)

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, please refer the complete markup and code behind through this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA)

Comment: @SatyajitMohanty please refer through this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA) for the MainWindow code and how the popup is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a way on how to solve the issue.  In my Popup dialog xaml implementation, I set HorizontalOffset to 0 and VerticalOffset to 180.  In that way, Popup dialog vertically overlays the buttons and ZIndex no longer matters.  WPFUser is right, it should work without explicitly defining ZIndex.

```
<Popup HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="180" IsOpen="False" Width="1080" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1920"
                       Name="EmergencyPopup" Placement="Top" AllowsTransparency="True">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource EdenParkInfoImg}" />
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="25"
                               MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="0,0,15,0">close X
                        </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
```